# How to add/use C# libraries in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, rider

I am trying to use `HttpClient` client however I am unable to use `using System.Net.Http;`. How to correctly use C# libraries in JetBrains Rider?

[image]

The os is linux.

Comment: Google "jetbrains rider add reference" > "For now there are only one way to edit them - editing *.csproj file."

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto This is no longer accurate with current releases of Rider.

Comment: as a little side note,  using doesn't import a library.  It's purely a namespace thing.     It's like saying "everything in this namespace I want to use as if it was in the global namespace".  It means you don't need to fully qualify everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`System.Net.Http` is not a standard reference included with console applications. You will need to add the reference explicitly to use it.

You can do this in Rider by right clicking the project in question, selecting Add > Add Reference. This will pop a dialog that will populate the system references. Once populated, find `System.Net.Http` and select it. Confirm the dialog. Your using should now work as expected.

Tested with Rider 2018.1 on windows.

Comment: What if it doesn't? Where are those System libraries actually located? My rider populates this dialog with my project's internals

Comment: @Konstantin If you can't reference it as a system library, I would recommend you add the `System.Net.Http` NuGet package instead of attempting to path to it directly, as that is likely to break the project in other people's environments.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that