# How to add ASP .Net Core Web Application library for Windows application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rider, windows-forms-core

I want to listen http requests by my windows forms application, in order to do this I want to add ASP .Net library for use  the web application.
I understand that this is a standard library, but I do not understand how to add it to the project

[image]

[image]

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458245/how-to-add-use-c-sharp-libraries-in-jetbrains-rider): "You can do this in Rider by right clicking the project in question, selecting Add > Add Reference.", but I can't find system libraries

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hosting ASP.NET Core API in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033762/hosting-asp-net-core-api-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: [How to: Add or remove references by using the Reference Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022)

Comment: [Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore` packages from nuget. I'm worried about outdated package warnings, but I haven't found a better solution.

[Hosting ASP.NET Core API in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033762/hosting-asp-net-core-api-in-a-windows-forms-application)

[image]